# Eclipse Gradle Plugin: <some pom file> cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I converted a Maven project to Gradle using `gradle init` after which `gradle install` successfully runs on the console. After an Eclipse gradle import, however, I get the error:

`Archive for required library: '[...].gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.jena/apache-jena-libs/2.12.0/[some hash value]/apache-jena-libs-2.12.0.pom' in project 'myproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file`.

Now what baffles me is that this file is not a ZIP (or JAR) file but a .pom file. Why does it try to open a POM as a ZIP and how can I fix this?

I use Gradle 2.3 with the Gradle IDE 3.6.3 on Eclipse 4.4 Luna on Arch Linux.

Comment: What do you mean with "Eclipse gradle import"? Have you tried a ```gradle cleanEclipse``` and does it work again afterwards? Can you run with ```-s``` and include the stacktrace?

Comment: I mean I use the import function from within the Eclipse IDE. I cannot give a stack trace unfortunately as the problem doesn't occur on the command line.

Comment: Have you tried using ```gradle cleanEclipse eclipse``` and import as an existing project into Eclipse?

Comment: Yes I tried that as well.

Comment: And did that work, or do you get the same error?

Comment: I got the same error (otherwise I would have marked the question as resolved).

Comment: Can you paste your ```build.gradle``` file? I think there is a bug because the reference library ```org.apache.jena:apache-jena-libs:2.12.0``` just has a POM but not a corresponding JAR. (see http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.jena%22%20AND%20a%3A%22apache-jena-libs%22)

Answer (score 8):

I've had a similar issue recently for jboss-ejb3-1.1.5.pom. It looks like a bug in Gradle Eclipse plugin because maven dependencies of type pom are included in the .classpath file. I think it should instead include dependencies mentioned within that .pom file. I get around this issue by adding a hack in my build.gradle file to not to include '.pom' files when eclipse plugin generates .classpath file.

```
eclipse {
            classpath {
                downloadSources = false;            
                // Following block of code is to remove .pom classpath entries in .classpath files 
                file {
                    whenMerged { classpath ->
                        Iterator i = classpath.entries.iterator()
                        while (i.hasNext()) {
                            org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.ClasspathEntry classpathEntry = i.next()
                            if(classpathEntry.kind.equals('lib') && classpathEntry.path.endsWith(".pom")) {
                                println('Removing ' + classpathEntry + ' from classpath entry')
                                i.remove()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with that dependency `jboss-ejb3-1.1.5` being transitive of `jbossas-as-tomcat-5.1.0.GA`. I managed to solve just by excluding it from the transitive dependency, as it was not necessary for my project.

Comment: Thanks! Onw comment though - in my gradle (v2.4) the kind of the pom is 'var' and not 'lib'

Answer (score 1):

Is the entry in the pom file for the dependencies correct

```
<dependency>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

otherwise it will be looking for the jar file in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the offending POM dependencies in the project properties->Java Build Path

it got my project compiling and I could debug my unit tests at least!